# How to compile older bootstrap3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to build custom bootstrap3. I visited official website and went here: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

The problem is that this application allows only to build the current (3.2) version, but I want to build 3.0.3 (latest that works properly on my website).

I just want to set gutter width to 0px. Is it possible to build older release?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you download the 3.0.3 master from [The Bootstrap Github Account](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/v3.0.3) and then change the variables in the LESS file (directory is `less/variables.less` line `249`). Then you would need to run a LESS compiler to create your CSS file.

Comment: Depending on your method of using Bootstrap, compiling could be done on the fly or through grunt.